# Can I control Breeze NamingConvention for a particular Query?

Tags: breeze

I have one Breeze Query where I would like to override the default camelCase I am generally using.

Is there some way to specify an overriding namingConvention when I call breeze.EntityQuery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you'll have to set your namingConvention before the query and then set it back after it executes.